# How to get current details from Windows Active Directory

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-active-directory

I tried to get current user details from Windows Active Directory using a .NetCore C# web application but I couldn't show them. I tried debugging and I have confirmed that my code already connected with my domain, because I could ensure my username and email details in debugging mode.

Here's my "Index.cshtml.cs" file

```
namespace Employees.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public void OnGet()
        {
            var username = User.Identity.Name;



            using (var context =new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "my Domain"))
            {
                var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, username);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    ViewData["UserName"] = user.Name;
                    ViewData["EmailAddress"] = user.EmailAddress;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And here's my "Index.cshtml" file:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}



    <p>@ViewData["EmployeeName"]</p>
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Someone commented and I couldn't get the point of his answer. That's why I asked for that, anyway he has been deleted his comment afterwards. @halfer don't get me wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I could check it in the basic project template when I made it with azure active directory.
Check below:

```
@using System.Security.Claims
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    var identity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity; // Azure AD V2 endpoint specific
    string preferred_username = identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "name")?.Value;
```

It's changed in visual studio 2019. This is what I am using now:

```
@using System.Security.Principal

<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right loginpartial">
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
        <li class="nav-item">
            <span class="navbar-text text-dark">Hello @User.Identity.Name.Substring(0,User.Identity.Name.IndexOf("@"))!</span>
        </li>
```

Comment: I could see that ViewData works in ActionResult function. I think it would be better to make model to get the information.

Comment: I will look into it. thank you so much and I really appreciate this. @jongkwan